# How to pre-populate a list with selected items using multi-select, knockout, and objects

Tags: javascript, html, object, knockout.js

I have a list of objects in my multi-select using Knockout. However when I try to setup beforehand what objects are selected nothing shows up as selected.  What do I need to do to make Ham show up in my example?

HTML:

```
<div class='liveExample'> 
    <p>Your values:</p>
    <select multiple="multiple" height="5" data-bind="options:allItems, selectedOptions:selectedItems, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'Id'"> </select>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var BetterListModel = function () {
    this.allItems = ko.observableArray([{Id: 1, Name: "Ham"}, {Id: 2, Name: "Cheese"}]); // Initial items
    this.selectedItems = ko.observableArray([{Id: 1, Name: "Ham"}]);                                // Initial selection

};

ko.applyBindings(new BetterListModel());
```

JS Fiddle for an example of what I'm trying to do.
https://jsfiddle.net/TwistedPurpose/e5qh9tq7/

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work, Uncaught ReferenceError: ko is not defined
    at (index):97

Comment: Updated it.  Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Apologies, it's because I'm using https on jsfiddle, and the knockout source file is http.

Comment: If you change the source to https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js it will work on https.

Comment: Gotcha.  That should do it.  Give it a try and let me know if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so here's the solution, you need to change the way you're writing the array back.

From this:

`this.selectedItems = ko.observableArray([{Id: 1, Name: "Ham"}]);`

To this:

`this.selectedItems = ko.observableArray([1]);`

---

Additionally, if you wanted to select more than one, you would do it like this:

`this.selectedItems = ko.observableArray([1, 2]);`

Comment: Awesome, it works!  Thank you!

It makes sense now I have to set the values to ID.